# Solid fill background which is based on the time of the day

Tags: applescript, macos, wallpaper

Live wallpapers have been available on Macs for a while, and I was wondering if there is a way to set up the wallpaper to be one of the solid fill colors available in the System preferences dialog, but vary the color pick based on the time of the day. Eg. light grey during daylight, and dark grey during the night. What's the easiest way of doing this?